# Invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used Erro

Tags: php, xml, microsoft-azure

> The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid
>   method (HTTP verb) is being used.

Esse erro está sendo apresentado, quando tento realizar o envio via `POST` de dados `XML` para um arquivo `PHP`.
 Escrevi um programa em `PHP` que recebe uma requisição via `POST` de dados `XML` e faz um response.
Quando o envio é feito, chamando este programa, acontece este erro mencionado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?php

/**
 * Lê o post enviado
 */
$dataPOST = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));

/**
 * Captura o conteúdo XML
 */
$xmlData = simplexml_load_string($dataPOST);

/**
 * Gravando conteudo no arquivo texto.
 */
$myFile = "data_backup.xml";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $xmlData;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);


/** ENVIO *****************************************************************/

/**  
 * Definir a URL POST e também payload
 */ 
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$timeStampGMT = time()+date("Z");
$timeStampGMT = gmdate("d/m/Y H:i:s",$timeStampGMT);

define('XML_POST_URL', 'http://cody.glpconnect.com'); 

$post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><state>ok</state>';

// Opções do header
$header  = "POST HTTP/1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/xml \r\n";
$header .= "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)." \r\n";
$header .= "Content-transfer-encoding: text \r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close \r\n\r\n"; 
$header .= $post_string;

/** 
 * Inicializar o identificador e definir opções 
 */ 
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, XML_POST_URL);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $header);

/** 
 * Verifica se há erros 
 */ 
if ( curl_errno($ch) ) { 
    $result = 'cURL ERROR -> ' . curl_errno($ch) . ': ' . curl_error($ch); 
} else { 
    $returnCode = (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
    switch($returnCode){ 
        case 200: 
            break; 
        default: 
            $result = 'HTTP ERROR -> ' . $returnCode; 
            break; 
    } 
} 

/** 
 * fecha o  handle 
 */ 
curl_close($ch); 

/** 
 * Saída dos resultados e do handle 
 */      
fwrite($fh, $result);
fclose($fh);


/** 
 * Saida do script 
 */ 
exit(0); 

?>
```

------------Editado ---------

```
/**
 * Lê o post enviado
 */
$dataPOST = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));
//$dataPOST = trim(file_get_contents($_POST['xml_post']));


/**
 * Captura o conteúdo XML
 */
$xmlData = simplexml_load_string($dataPOST);

/**
 * Gravando conteudo no arquivo texto.
 */
$myFile = "data_backup.xml";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $xmlData;
fwrite($fh, "Data POST:\r\n");
fwrite($fh, $dataPOST);
fwrite($fh, "\r\n");
fwrite($fh, "STRING DATA:\r\n");
fwrite($fh, var_dump($stringData));

/** ENVIO *****************************************************************/

/**  
 * Definir a URL POST e também payload
 */ 
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$timeStampGMT = time()+date("Z");
$timeStampGMT = gmdate("d/m/Y H:i:s",$timeStampGMT);


define('XML_POST_URL', 'http://cody.glpconnect.com'); 

$post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><state>ok</state>';

// Opções do header
$header  = "POST HTTP/1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/xml \r\n";
$header .= "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)." \r\n";
$header .= "Content-transfer-encoding: text \r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close \r\n\r\n"; 
$header .= $post_string;

/** 
 * Inicializar o identificador e definir opções 
 */ 
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, XML_POST_URL);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $header);

/** 
 * Verifica se há erros 
 */ 
if ( curl_errno($ch) ) { 
    $result = 'cURL ERROR -> ' . curl_errno($ch) . ': ' . curl_error($ch); 
} else { 
    $returnCode = (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
    switch($returnCode){ 
        case 200: 
            break; 
        default: 
            $result = 'HTTP ERROR -> ' . $returnCode; 
            break; 
    } 
} 

/** 
 * fecha o  handle 
 */ 
curl_close($ch); 

/** 
 * Saída dos resultados e do handle 
 */      
fwrite($fh, "\r\n");
fwrite($fh, "Resultado:\r\n");
fwrite($fh, "\r\n");
fwrite($fh, $result);
fclose($fh);


/** 
 * Saida do script 
 */ 
exit(0); 

 ?>
```

Comment: Eu não entendi seu problema.

Comment: Editei o post, veja se consegue compreender melhor agora.

Comment: melhorou mas ainda não está o ideal, poste também o código, para poder tentar simular seu erro,

Comment: vou editar e colocar o código para você ver

Comment: Como você envia o xml por post ? pelo seu código você está abrindo o arquivo, e trabalhado nele.

Comment: Exato, eu recebo um arquivo XML de uma API via post

Comment: Após isso  retorna os dados, essa mensagem está sendo gerada no momento em que o pessoal que envia o XML tenta se comunicar

Comment: então esse código seu não está tratando um envio via post. eu vou mudar ele para receber esse arquivo por post ai você testa ele.

Answer (score 0):

Adicionei o medo de envio do tipo [`$_POST[]`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php) para que ao enviar por **POST** ele trabalhe em cima do arquivo temporário.

Não me atentei e entender todo o seu script, mas apenas ao meio de post, defini o name como `xml_post`, basta definir o mesmo nome da sua api de envio.

```
<?php

/**
 * Lê o post enviado
 */

$dataPOST = trim(file_get_contents($_POST['xml_post']));
/**
 * Captura o conteúdo XML
 */
$xmlData = simplexml_load_string($dataPOST);

/**
 * Gravando conteudo no arquivo texto.
 */
$myFile = "data_backup.xml";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $xmlData;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);


/** ENVIO *****************************************************************/

/**  
 * Definir a URL POST e também payload
 */ 
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$timeStampGMT = time()+date("Z");
$timeStampGMT = gmdate("d/m/Y H:i:s",$timeStampGMT);

define('XML_POST_URL', 'http://cody.glpconnect.com'); 

$post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><state>ok</state>';

// Opções do header
$header  = "POST HTTP/1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/xml \r\n";
$header .= "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)." \r\n";
$header .= "Content-transfer-encoding: text \r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close \r\n\r\n"; 
$header .= $post_string;

/** 
 * Inicializar o identificador e definir opções 
 */ 
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, XML_POST_URL);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $header);

/** 
 * Verifica se há erros 
 */ 
if ( curl_errno($ch) ) { 
    $result = 'cURL ERROR -> ' . curl_errno($ch) . ': ' . curl_error($ch); 
} else { 
    $returnCode = (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
    switch($returnCode){ 
        case 200: 
            break; 
        default: 
            $result = 'HTTP ERROR -> ' . $returnCode; 
            break; 
    } 
} 

/** 
 * fecha o  handle 
 */ 
curl_close($ch); 

/** 
 * Saída dos resultados e do handle 
 */      
fwrite($fh, $result);
fclose($fh);


/** 
 * Saida do script 
 */ 
exit(0); 

?>
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, acima me equivoquei e disse que era recebimento de um "arquivo", mas não é de arquivo, são apenas dados via XML que são recebidos via POST, não existe arquivo.

Comment: Entendi vou mudar ai você testa

Comment: Ok, estou testando pelo Postman, caso dê certo, já retorno a você.

Comment: Acabei de fazer um teste no Postman, porém ainda continuo recebendo este erro, ontem ainda contatei o suporte da Azure e estou aguardando uma medida. enfim o erro que recebo é este que coloquei no post.

Comment: @JoãoVictor roda uma teste na primeira linha do php `var_dump($_POST['xml_post']);` veja se vai receber algum output se receber e alguma parte do seu código, caso não e com o seu servidor

Comment: realizei algumas mudanças aqui e debbuguei colocando para gravar o que está me retornando, porém agora o problema está sendo no retorno dos dados, vou atualizar o código para você ver